# Is probability of occupancy exponential?

Tags: probability

I have 100 empty cups and throw a ball at them. Assume I always hit a cup, and if the ball hits a cup that already has a ball in it, it bounces off and is wasted. For the first throw, the chance that the ball will go in any cup is X times 100 (the number of empty cups to hit), and as more balls occupy cups the chance goes down.

Now assume someone else is playing against me. When either of us hit a cup with the others ball within, we exchange their ball for ours. The winner is the one who fills the cups entirely.

I don't quite know how to describe this relationship. The other player and I are in an equilibrium, of course, but what is the correct term to describe the increasing difficulty of getting a ball in a cup as one gets closer to winning the game? As occupancy increases, chance decreases. Could I say it exponentially decreases?

Comment: In practice, this game would probably never finish if the two players were anything like equal standard as it would be too easy to prevent the other player from occupying all of the cups. If you calculated the probabilities, you'd probably have factorials as well as powers, so probably not really exponential.

Comment: I think it may be easier to consider a simplified game where there are $n$ cups, and any time a player throws, they are equally likely to make the ball in any one cup. Using your rules, the probability of, say, player 1 winning given he only has one more cup unoccupied would then be $1/n$, or $1/n^2$ if player 2 is supposed to throw before him.